# Day after max date in data

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am loading data into a table. I don't have any info on how frequent or when the source data is loaded, all I know is I need data from the source to run my script.

Here's the issue, if I run max(date) I get the latest date from the source, but I don't know if the data is still loading. I've ran into cases where I've only  gotten a percentage of the data. Thus, I need the next business day after max date.

I want to know is there a way to get the second latest date in the system. I know I can get max(date) - 1, but that give me literally the day after. I don't need the literal day after.

Example, if I run the script on Tuesday, max(date) will be Monday, but since weekend are not in the source system, I need to get Friday instead of Monday.

```
DATE
---------
2017-04-29
2017-04-25
2017-04-21
2017-04-19
2017-04-18
2017-04-15
2017-04-10

max(date) = 2017-04-29
```

how do I get 2017-04-25?

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: What's the expected result if you add another row with date 2017-04-29?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of SQL Server, you can use a windowing function like [`row_number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
select [Date]
from
(
  select [Date],
    rn = row_number() over(order by [Date] desc)
  from #yourtable
) d
where rn = 2
```

Here is a [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/666087).

Should you have multiple of the same date, you can perform a `distinct` first:

```
;with cte as
(
  select distinct [date]
  from #yourtable
)
select [date]
from
(
  select [date],
    rn = row_number() over(order by [date] desc)
  from cte
) x
where rn = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number and get second as below

```
select * from ( select *, Rown= row_number() over (order by date desc) from yourtable ) a
   where a.RowN = 2
```

Comment: Provided Dates are distinct,  Just for fun add another 2017-04-29

Answer (score 0):

More recent SQL Server versions support `FETCH FIRST`:

```
select date
from tablename
order by date desc
offset 1 fetch first 1 row only
```

`OFFSET 1` means skip one row. (The 2017-04-29 row.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, just for example sake...

```
SELECT MIN(A.date)
FROM
(
SELECT  TOP 2 DISTINCT date
FROM    YourTable AS C
ORDER BY date DESC
) AS A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte([DATE])
AS
(
SELECT '2017-04-29' union all
SELECT '2017-04-25' union all
SELECT '2017-04-21' union all
SELECT '2017-04-19' union all
SELECT '2017-04-18' union all
SELECT '2017-04-15' union all
SELECT '2017-04-10' 
)
SELECT [DATE] FROM
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Seq)-1 As Rno FROM
(
SELECT *,MAX([DATE])OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))Seq FROM cte
)dt
)Final
WHERE Final.Rno=1
```

OutPut

```
DATE
-----
2017-04-25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use FIRST_VALUE with a dynamic date something like DATEADD(DD, -1, GETDATE()). The example below has the date hard coded.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRST_VALUE([date]) OVER(ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS FirstDate
FROM CTE 
WHERE [date] < '2017-04-25'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([DATE] DATE)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('2017-04-29'),
('2017-04-25'),
('2017-04-21'),
('2017-04-19'),
('2017-04-18'),
('2017-04-15'),
('2017-04-10');

SELECT


MAX([DATE]) AS [DATE]
FROM @T
WHERE  DATENAME(DW,[DATE]) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
```